# Missing com.CorePlot.Framework.docset bundle for core-plot documentation install into xCode

Tags: xcode, ios, core-plot

I am very new to both Objective-C and iOS programming. I am working my way through creating some graphs using core-plot and want to access some documentation that might help explain the examples given.

The readme file says in order to install the documentation I must:

> 1. Quit Xcode
> 2. Copy the com.CorePlot.Framework.docset bundle into ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/
> 3. Launch Xcode, and browse Core Plot documentation in the Documentation browser

---

This looks easy but I am having a problem locating the "CorePlot.Framework.docset" bundle. Perhaps I am missing something simple?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using one of the release packages or building from source?

If you're using a release package without the installer, the docset is in "CorePlot x.x.x/Documentation" after unzipping the archive.

If you're using the installer, it should have placed the docset in the right place.

If you're building from source, follow the instructions [here](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/DocumentationPolicy) to install Doxygen and Graphviz. Open the CorePlot-CocoaTouch project and build the *Documentation* target. The build script will install the docset automatically.

Eric

Comment: Thanks, this really helped.  My main problem was that I was using mac ports to install Doxygen and Graphviz.  Once I manually installed them using the link in that document I was then able to build the documentation set which now shows up in xcode.  Thanks!